# Failed bootstrap grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just want to create a simple two column section, but it didn't work.
Actually this problem have already bothered me for such a long time. Sometime I can fix it, sometime I can't. So please help me!

```
<section>
<div class="cotainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img src="../img/adobe-dreamweaver--Feature_1290x688_MS.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>Web-Design</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: this is what it's look like]

Answer (score 0):

Include bootstrap.css in you HTML head and fix your code: Check class names and add img-responsive class to images in those columns.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../img/adobe-dreamweaver--Feature_1290x688_MS.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>Web-Design</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the next thing is to read the Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com.

Comment: Without knowing anything else I assume your bootstrap.css is not loading correctly.